# Alien disease for repopulation

Tags: story-identification

I know this is going to be crazy easy for someone, but I forget... what was the book series where the aliens attacked earth, wiped out a bunch of people, thought they were going to rule it so gave us a disease where girls were just as horny as guys so we could repopulate really quickly?

Comment: I always think it is funny... my question and the other question have pretty much nothing in common except for the answer... but it is a 'similar question' :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I no longer have the set of books, but from memory, this is one of the *Troy Rising* trilogy by John Ringo.

The first book 'Live free or die' has a mass plague caused by the alien Horvaths, a lot of people die, a large number of blonde haired people survive.

It is then noticed by a Dr Johannsen that the females are now in a monthly 'heat cycle' and also subconsciously crave to be pregnant. This becomes known as Johannsen's Syndrome.

### A further note on this book:

It's the one where the aliens are addicted to Maple Syrup and want Earth for a syrup plantation....the book is often confused with the one where the aliens are addicted to coffee (which I can't remember the title of!)

### Update

[This rant from an outraged Goodreads reviewer](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/467599976) mentions the selective disease .....

> The author of this atrocity, John Ringo, should take a lesson from Heinlein.
>
> In Ringo's world, anyone who isn't actively rooting for poor brown people to die is an idiot. I am not exaggerating. There is a point in the book where all the poor brown people die, and the red neck hero of the book declares it is a real shame, but applauds how much this is going to improve the economy. It would be one thing if this was written from the perspective of a red neck fascist, but it is pretty clearly a fantasy world where every even vaguely lefty decision results in doom, and every fascist decision in a win.
>
> My favorite part is when, after all the poor brown people are killed, a virus makes it so that blond women (and only blond women) go into heat and it makes them desperate to breed and more fertile, thus ensuring that the future of the human race will be blond hair blue eyed white people. I didn't even make that up.

Comment: I totally remembered the maple syrup thing but didn't remember that this was the same series. Thanks.

Comment: Looking over the goodreads reviews I can find the Horvaths, and the maple syrup... but I can't find the disease.

Comment: I'm wondering if we got confused and this is part of the Legacy of the Alendata series.

Comment: I've updated the answer with part of a Goodreads review to confirm it's a 'Troy Rising' book

Comment: >>every even vaguely lefty decision results in doom

ROTFL Yeah, well, about that.... :)

Comment: Specifically, it's from "Live Free or Die", the first in the trilogy. And the bit about populating the world with blonds (note that eye color is not specified in the book) is clearly due to limited knowledge on the part of the alien attackers. Also, the reviewer fails to note that the blonds who go into heat will also lose the normal protective features of fertilization which protect against multiple births, so it's entirely possible that, in the absence of very good prenatal care, the affected "blond blue eyed white people" will actually decrease in numbers due to high infant mortality.